# Can't Import Python File Holding Data To Use As A Function - ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import

I have two python files, x.py and data.py, both of which are in the same directory.  The *only thing* that data.py contains is the following:

```
def get_data():
  data = [{'h': hashID, 'x': x_position, 'y': y_position}, .... ]
  return data
```

In my other x.py python file, I'm trying to use this function to get the data like so:

```
from data import get_data
....
....
date = get_data()
for i in range(0, len(date)):
  XPos = date[i]['x']
  YPos = date[i]['y']
....
```

However, whenever I try to run x.py, I get the following:
ImportError: cannot import name get_data

I've tried placing the import inside the function that I'm calling it from, rearranging the import call, and even trying:

```
import os
import sys
scriptpath = "...\data.py"
# Add the directory containing your module to the Python path (wants absolute paths)
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(scriptpath))
import data
```

These tricks usually have me get a "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_data'", or "TypeError: object of type 'module' has no len()."

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Obvious suggestions: 1. Circular import; 2. One module shadowing another with the same name.

Comment: If you start Python interactively, run `import data`, and then `print data.__file__`, does it show you the path you expect?

Comment: If you start with an empty directory, can you create a simple reproducer for this behavior?  Using your samples here everything seems to work with errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the folder to the pythonpath?
In the console:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/folder/
python /path/to/folder/x.py
```

where /path/to/folder is the path of the folder where your files are.